# How to check if an XML node contains text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

How can I check if a XML node contains text, or only empty nodes?

Example: Let's say we have the following XML:

```
<text>
   <p> </p>
   <p> </p>
</text>
```

(Note the whitespace between the p tags)

In a different XML, we have the following XML:

```
<text>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
</text>
```

I'd like the test to pass in the second example, but not in the first, as the second example contains text, but the first contains empty nodes.

Is there a way to easily achieve this?

(I use XSLT 2.0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

at the top of your style sheet then the parser will ignore text nodes in your input document that consist entirely of whitespace. Among other things this means that your example `p` elements with spaces will be treated the same as completely empty ones. For example a template matching `text[p/text()]` would match the `text` element in your second example but not ones whose `p` children are all empty (or contain only space).

Answer (score 8):

I think `normalize-space` does what you want, e.g. this will 'pass':

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(/text/p) != ''">
    ...
</xsl:if>
```

`normalize-space`  will trim all leading and trailing whitespace from a string, which will leave text behind in your second example, but remove all characters in your first example allowing you to compare against the empty string `''`.

Note it also compresses multiple whitespace characters in sequence into a single character, so for example `hello<space><space><space>there` would become `hello<space>there`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space (XPath 1)

Answer (score 8):

**Use**:

```
p[normalize-space()]
```

This selects any `p` child of the context (current) node, whose string-value is not the empty string or a whitespace-only string.